# Check if user is authenticated with Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito User Pool and Federated Identities in my Android app to manage my users and their connection to other AWS services. I've been able to implement the authentication successfully and even sign out users with this code:

```
public void logOut() {
    credentialsProvider.clearCredentials();
    getUserPool().getCurrentUser().signOut();
}
```

However, I have no idea how to check if there is a user currently logged in. I can't see how I can check if the current user from the user pool is logged in, since `CognitoUser.getSession()` automatically triggers the authentication workflow. And I can't see if there are cached credentials in the credentials provider because `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()` automatically does a network request if credentials are not present.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The session have a "isValid()" method, you can validate against that.